# Why my nodejs POST request returns null values (I use postman)?

Tags: node.js, express, postman

When I use post request it only posts null I use postman

```
app.post("/books",async (req,res)=>{
  try{
      
  const {book_name,book_author,book_desc} = req.body;
  const newBook =  await pool.query("INSERT INTO library(book_name,book_author,book_desc) VALUES($1,$2,$3) RETURNING *",
  [book_name,book_author,book_desc]);
  res.json(newBook.rows[0]);
   }
  catch(err){
      console.error(err.message);
  } 
  
})
```

This is the code and output of postman:

{
"book_name": "abc",
"book_author": "def",
"book_desc": "gjl"

}

Output:

{
"book_id": 1,
"book_name": null,
"book_author": null,
"book_desc": null
}

Comment: when you do console.log(newBook.rows[0]) before res.json, what is printed out?

Comment: It is still null

Comment: Could it be because nothing is returned by the insert? meaning no rows were inserted?

Comment: the output is what it returned problem is with the values i think problem can be about giving multiple values to req.body but i still couldnt found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `json` parser so your req.body is not getting book_name, book_author and book_desc.

use `json()` middleware before the post code and you are good to go.

For TS:

```
import express, { json } from "express";
app.use(json()) // use json parser to convert the body to json for upcoming method to consume

app.post("/books",async (req, res)=>{
...
})
```

For JS:

```
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.json())

app.post("/books",async (req, res)=>{
...
})
```

Comment: I wrote parser at the top

Comment: can you confirm the req.body is not empty before inserting to SQL

Comment: I tried to get it before and after the SQL code nothing changed so problem is either about the SQL code or about the req.body equation

Comment: It is empty in both cases btw

Comment: how you post the data in postman? I uploaded my postman setting. Can you cross-check yours. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17HJFvxfH6tnAMeEJ4GapaBVy8sMBKxbI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I forgot it Javascript thank you this solved my problem.